# inject html markup around random words in string using c#

Tags: c#, html

I want to inject html markup around random words in string like "this is a string for this question". The result should be like `"this is a string <legend title="xyz">for</legend> this question"`. I want to do it using c#.

Comment: I assume by "random" you mean "arbitrary" and not actually random - *or do you?*

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx):

```
// Input string
string someMsg = "this is a string for this question";

// Match word boundaries
string pattern = "\bfor\b";
string replacement = "<legend title=\"for\">for</legend>";

// Create the regex object
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
// Replace all instances of <pattern> with <replacement>
string result = rgx.Replace(someMsg, replacement);
```

Obviously, you could make this more generic to your needs, but the Regex object provides the functionality you're looking for.